# how to fit ar(1) model with predetermined value of autocorrelation parameter in R?

Tags: time-series, arima

I have the following data:

```
ar <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.9), n=M1) + 10
```

How to fit an AR(1) model to simulated data above with ar parameter=0.5?

EDIT:
I used:

```
fit <- arima(ar, fixed = 0.5, include.mean = T)        
fit
```

Call:

```
arima(x = ar, include.mean = T, fixed = 0.5))         
Coefficients:     
intercept  
   0.5
```

This is not correct. I want my fitted model to have the mean (which should be approximately 10) and the `ar_parameter=0.5`.

Pls help

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Is it the population coefficient or its *estimate* that you want to be 0.5?

Comment: I would like the estimate of autocorrelation parameter to be 0.5.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `stats::arima` and `forecast::Arima` accept a parameter `fixed` which will fix certain parameters to a given value, and fit the remaining parameters. You need to pass the value `NA` for any parameters that you don't want to fix.

Therefore, you can do this:

```
mod <- stats::arima(ar, c(1,0,0), include.mean = TRUE, fixed = c(0.5, NA))
```

This will fit an AR(1) where the the AR coefficient is fixed at 0.5 and the constant is fitted freely. See the documentation for the convention on the ordering of parameters in `fixed`.